# How to do a inner join to get only the values saved on the table

Tags: python, django

How can I get only the `law` saved from an specific `user` in `marked` table?

When a user register a law, the usuer id (`user_id`) and the law id (`law_id`) is saved in `marked` table.
How can I get only the laws register by the user and order by law `updated_at` field ?

My model:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)    
    description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank = True, null=True)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        'Updated at', auto_now=True

    )

class Marked(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Lei', related_name='marcacaoArtigos')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='markedUser', related_name='markedUser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since the related name to user in the `Marked` table is `markedUser`, you would do

```
user1 = User.objects.get(id=x)
user1.markedUser.all()
```

This would return to you a set of all Laws that are paired with `user1` in the `Marked` table.  Judging by your related names, I don't think you fully understand how the relations work.  I'd suggest reading about them here: [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: I got this error: `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: yeah, so to access them as a list, you do `user1.markedUser.all()`. I can't remember if you need parentheses. try with and without

Comment: Now I didn't get error, but it's not returning `law` values to my view, like `{{law.name}}`

Comment: oh, you didn't specify what you were using this for. It returns instances of the `Marked` model.  So let's say you name the first instance in the `.all()` list `marked1`.  `marked1.law.name` will give you what you want.

Comment: awesome!! That's working. That's just one point, it's returnin some values repeated, how can I bring just one?

Comment: can you be more specific, i don't quite understand what you mean. maybe edit your answer with your code and the output (or a shorter example of the output, if it's too long)

Comment: I'm sorry for that. In my `marked` table, I have more than one tuple with the same `law` value, so when I do `markeds= user1.markedUser.all()` I got some repeated values. I'm trying to use `distinct`but is not working. I'm hope I was clear.

Comment: Example of the output `{{marked.law.name}}`: `law 8666, law 12987, law 8666,  law 8666, law 8745`

Comment: ah. so to get distinct (law, user) pairs, you do the following: `user1.markedUser.order_by().distinct()`

Comment: it didnt' works, but ok, no problem. Tku so much for all.

Comment: you can also enforce distinct pairings by using `unique_together` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together